# How to get whole record from ShowRecord component in react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I have DataGrid and I use ShowButton to get the detail of the data and show it in antoher page. When I click the showClick it calls the right path and opens the page with the right path "details/{id}/show" but i need to some other data form the list grid in the detail page. is there any way to pass the whole record to the show page?

list.tsx

```
 <DataGrid whiteSpace="nowrap" rowClick="edit">
                <ShowButton label="detail"  resource="details"/>
```

index.tsx

```
<Resource name="details" key="details" show={Details} />,
```

detail.tsx

```
const Details= () => {
  return (
    <EditBase>
```

i have tried record prop, but i couldn't obtain it in the detail page